# Basename/URL reuse and Pagerank

Tags: seo, google, pagerank

I'm working with an SEO consultant that is recommending basename/URL reuse. The idea is that Google recognizes a given URL as high value and that URL will maintain value over time if the content is fresh. I'd like to know if this is a valid SEO strategy.

So, we'll start with an article under:

```
http://example.com/some-search-term
```

Then, a couple of weeks later we'll "move" the content:

```
http://example.com/some-search-term becomes
http://example.com/12345
```

and a new article is published under:

```
http://example.com/some-search-term
```

Does this scheme make sense? It seems to break a lot of the assumptions about URLs, for end users (bookmarks break) and third party sites (Facebook like counts point to the wrong content).

Comment: The worst SEO strategy that i have heard..
Google is just another foolish head.
Especially when the hummingbird updates are coming you blog is going to suffer..

Answer (score 2):

If you move the content that was indexed under: `http://example.com/some-search-term` to: `http://example.com/12345`, in attempt to maintain the same value, you'd have to do a [301 redirect](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) to let Google know that it moved.

If you don't, then the next time Google indexes `http://example.com/some-search-term`, it will find the new content there and evaluate it accordingly, and it will index and evaluate `http://example.com/12345` as a new page.

If you continually redirect a URL elsewhere, you'll also run into issues with caching - see this for more on that: [301 Redirects: The Horror That Cannot Be Uncached](http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/)

As you might suspect, this seems to be an attempt at SEO manipulation, which Google spends a lot of time trying to circumvent. Generally if it impacts users, it's not a good SEO strategy either.